# Changing the format of the value inserted in excel or making it more readable

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

1. Is there any formula in excel by which we can change the format in a way to make it easier to read

### Example :

Existing:                17752528.25 
Expected:               17,752,528.25

2. Along with the above thing, if any value inserted in the any cell of excel then that value can be entered with leading zeros without the need to change the cell format

### Example :

should allow to insert the value in a cell as : 00098756 i.e with the leading zeros and even after switching the cell or saving the sheet, the value remain as it is.

Or do i need to write a custom program using VBA for both the scenario.

Thank you !

Comment: https://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/excel/format-numbers-in-thousands-and-millions-in-excel-reports/

Comment: For the leading zeroes you will first need to format the cells as Text.  Or prepend your values with `'`

Comment: If you have a fixed length (e.g. 8 digits), you can enter a custom number format like `00000000` - this will display leading zeros. However, if you want to keep exactly what the user enters, you have to deal with strings. Rule of thumb: If you want to do calculations, you have a number, else you have a string (a zip code may contain only digits, but you never want to multiply it by 2 - save it as string)

Comment: @Tim Williams , as mentioned, i do not want to change the cell format. As formatting the cells , selecting the custom category will fix both the points. But what i want to know, is there any possibility to enter the value without changing the format.

Comment: @FunThomas no, its not a fixed length input . is there anyway of handling this using any formula so that the leading zeros will not be trimmed when a user enters any value ? may be for comma separated value i can develop some program using VBA.

Answer (score 0):

You have to carefully think about your data and data types on the one hand and it's representation on the other.

Your first example looks like a real number for me, 17 millon 752 thousand... If it is, you could use it in any calculation. Displaying it with thousand separator is a matter of formatting. The *value* of this number doesn't change, no matter how you format it, the format only defines how it is *represented* to the user. No matter if you display it as `17752528,25`, `17,752,528.25`, `1,78E+07`, the *value* stays the same. And on my computer, it would be displayed as `17.752.528,25` as my computer is configured to have a comma as decimal separator - but still, the value would be the same.

If I am wrong and it is a string, you need some coding to get the commas in it, but that would change the string, so it's no longer a matter of formatting. The value without and the value with the commas would be total different.

Now, if it comes to input where leading zeroes matter, you have clearly not a number but a string. If the user enters `00098756` and it would be a number, the *value* would be `98756`. You can change the *representation* to display leading zeroes, but you will not know how many leading zeroes the user entered.

To keep the zeroes exactly as the user entered, you need either to format the cell as `text` or the user has to enter a leading `'`, else Excel will interpret the input as number and immediately throw away the zeroes. Now, you have a string that contain only digits, but keep in mind that `00098756` is not equal to `98756` or `98,756`. You can, however, use the `value`-function in Excel (or `val` in VBA) to get it's numerical value.

Comment: Thanks @FunThomas for your comment.The requirement has been revoked as of now, so i did not tried more on this. when i will proceed with this in near future, your suggestion will help a lot.